# Highcharts - Hiding plot line behind plot label

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts

The problem is demonstrated below in the JSFiddle. I want the line behind the text to not be shown. I'd like to just set the background color of the label to white, and have the plot line be hidden behind the label.

I want the label and plot line to look like this:

[image: Plot Line]

Anyone have any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/qajb5vmo/

Here's the example code I'm using to demonstrate my problem.

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        type: 'datetime',
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6),           
            label: {
                text: 'Plot line',
                textAlign: 'center',
                rotation: 0
            }
        }]
    },

    yAxis: {
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but `color: 'transparent'`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qajb5vmo/1/ ?

Comment: @pritishvaidya I've updated the post with an image of what i want

Comment: @HalvorStrand I've updated the post with an image of what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable labels to be drawn as html. It will cause that they will be rendered  above the svg elements.

```
label: {
                y: 20,
                useHTML: true,
                text: 'Plot line',
                textAlign: 'center',
                rotation: 0,
                style: {
                  backgroundColor: 'white'
                }
            }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/qajb5vmo/5/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the position of the label by setting the `x` and `y` axis as shown in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qajb5vmo/2/)

```
label: {
                    text: 'Plot line',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    rotation: 0,
                    y:-10
                }
```

Comment: yah i tried this solution but it goes off screen for me. I could increase the size of the highcharts container but id have to redo a lot of css. Ideally theres a solution that allows me to set the background color of the label to white, or decrease the length of the line.

Comment: there is no need to add a lot of css,you can adjust the area *width* and *height*  by `plotAreaWidth` and `plotAreaHeight`

Comment: That's true, in most cases that would work. I'm using a vuejs highcharts plugin that doesnt show the title of the chart, and therefore anything above the graph gets hidden. I dont know why, must be a bug with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack to reduce the line height of the plot line. I don't recommend using this method as this is a hack.

http://jsfiddle.net/qod5hzb2/

```
  const pathSvgArray = $('.highcharts-plot-lines-0 path').attr('d').split('');
  pathSvgArray[2] = '75';

  $('.highcharts-plot-lines-0 path').attr('d', pathSvgArray.join(' '));
```

Comment: This has to be done on resize events too. Not an ideal solution.